# Fuzzy text in Qt application?

Tags: qt, user-interface, fonts

I wrote a Qt application that drawing text, when using a certain font (Inconsolata) in small point sizes, it looked fuzzy:

[image]

But when using other font (Courier New, etc..) it's just fine:

[image]

What strange here is that other applications using that font looks normal, here is a contrast (left is vim, right is my application):

[image: Contrast of same font, different application]

What would be the problem here?

Environment:

Window 7 Ultimate 64-bit

PySide 1.2.2 & Qt 4.8

Inconsolata.otf (http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html)

Code example (the problem is more serious on a dark scheme):

```
from PySide.QtGui import *

app = QApplication([])
label = QLabel('hello\nworld')
label.setStyleSheet('QLabel {background: #000; color: #fff;}')
label.setFont(QFont('Inconsolata', 11))
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Which OS and environment are you testing in? What Qt version is this and is freetype used (on Linux, check with ldd on the Qt libraries)? What kind of font (ttf, otf, etc.) is Inconsolata coming from? Does it also happen with other fonts? If yes, do they have anything in common? Is it reproducible with a minimal example, too? (Simple main() showing a QLabel)

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the [Qt font style strategy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#StyleStrategy-enum) of your QFont and see what gives the best result.

For example to enable antialiasing on your application's default font, you can do:

```
QFont font = QApplication::font();
font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);
QApplication::setFont(font);
```